# Bootstrap-select render dropdown ontop

Tags: bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

unfortunately I have the issue that once you have a bootstap-select inside a DIV with overflow hidden, the options gets hidden as well.
I guess there has to be a fix out there to render / show the dropdown on the highest layer (document or body). Is someone aware of this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? (data-container="body")

http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#container